# Passing the date selected by the date time picker to a database in VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datetimepicker

I am new to programming and when I tries to pass the date selected by the date time picker, it says a error like failed to convert from string to date type.

This is a part of the code that I Used.

```
connection.Open()
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Students (DATE) VALUES(@DOB),connection)     
command.Parameters.Add("@dob", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker.Value.Date   
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
connection.close()
```

Comment: The only problem that I can see is the Date field. Date is a reserved word in MS-Acces, To use that field from code you need to put it between square brackets _[Date]_

Comment: Actuallyn it wasn't the Date in my code I wrote it here to give some idea.

Comment: And on MS-Access table what is the datatype of the involved field? (DATE) Is it of type DateTime?

Comment: Yes it is.And it is formatted to short data

Comment: What exactly is the error message, and where did you get it ? In vb, or in your database ?
Since you command is correct, the parameter adding is also correct, it must be somewhere in your code or by your table design.

Comment: Message=Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.Error is from VB

Comment: Thanks I think I may have found a solution

Answer (score 0):

SelSQL01.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker.Value.Date)

That´s work in SQL.